# Creating an IPTABLES chain, whose rules are ignored, unless the packet is from a certain port?

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

I want to confirm the following.  If I create a chain whose first rule is:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465 -j name
```

Does that mean that any further specified rules in the chain, are not checked, unless the packet is from those ports?

I'm using `fail2ban`, and I created a filter with a ban rule that specifies port 25, 465, using `-m multiport --dports 25,465`.  But this filter ended up creating a large enough number of rules, that occasionally the `ksoftirqd` process would use a lot of CPU, and the network would become slow.  I noticed this occurred, when the server had a lot of I/O occurring on other ports.

I assume each packet was looking at all the rules in my chain.  I'm hoping I can avoid this, by adding the first rule seen above, so that packets not to ports 25 & 465, will not bother to check the rest of the rules in that chain. If this doesn't do that, I would appreciate knowing any other possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not "from" but "to". `--dports` lists *destination* ports. The rule as you written, means: "if the packet was sent to my service listening on TCP port 25 or 465, process it in the chain `name`". How it will be processed depends on the contents of that chain. If it doesn't match any *final action* (`ACCEPT`, `REJECT`, `DROP`) rule in that chain, or if it matches a rule with the `RETURN` action, its processing will continue in the calling chain (`INPUT`) with the rule following this one.

By default `fail2ban` creates a chain and a rule which invokes the chain for only packets destined to certain port (unless you are using `...-allports` action, which is not default). Into that chain it adds a DROP rule for each banned IP. So, for instance, web server packets will not be sent for processing to the chain created for `sshd` supplied jail. Therefore, deliberately "excluding" certain ports from fail2ban processing in a way you suggest is not productive; it already works like this.

To avoid creating chain with too many rules with fail2ban, investigate *ipset*-related actions. Instead of creating a chain `f2b-jailname` it creates an [IP set](https://ipset.netfilter.org/) and a single rule which match refers to the ipset. Each banned IP is added into the ipset, instead of creating a separate rule in the chain. The ipset has O(1) complexity characteristic, which means its processing speed does not depend on the number of items in it; it can contain up to 65536 items.

To use that, in short, you need to override default `banaction = iptables` with `banaction = iptables-ipset` for your jails. You should never modify distribution-supplied configuration files; instead, create `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` file where you add your overrides:

```
[postfix]
bantime = 1h
enabled = true
banaction = iptables-ipset
```

(This will use the supplied `postfix` mail filter, and react on all `smtpd`-type services. If you use another mail server, adjust accordingly.)

Other way to achieve better firewall efficiency is to start using [`nftables`](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Main_Page) framework instead of `iptables`. It has features of IP sets *integrated*, and you can use it with fail2ban using the `banaction = nftables`. The efficiency gain for large sets will be roughly the same.